# Why does my array of objects not pass to the child when using VueJS 3 dynamic component

Tags: vue.js

I want to mount/unmount 2 components in my Vue 3 app. I had originally done it like the example here and it worked fine.

```
<ResultSimple
    v-for="(result, index) in myResults"
    :result="result"
    :index="index"
    :key="result"
    />
```

I was trying to improve my code and followed the example given in this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oi9dI6tG6bs). I can see that the concept work for me i.e. it is changing which component is mounted but it is not passing the data.

```
 <component
    :is="activeResults"
    v-for="(result, index) in myResults"
    :result="result"
    :index="index"
    :key="result"
    />
```

Instead it looks like this in developer tools:

```
<the-name result="[object Object]" index="9"></the-name>
```

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: Make sure that the key is a unique identifier for each item in the `myResults` array. Use a key to something unique, like :`key="result.id"` or any other property which is unique.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but I still cant get it to work. I think it must be something like this though so I will keep trying :)

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when we did not defined the `prop` on the relevant component. Can you please verify that you defined `result` prop properly in your `<the-name>` component with the expected value type which is an object.

In child component, prop should be declared like this **:**

```
export default {
    props: {
        result: Object,
    },
}
```

If it isn't defined as a prop then it'll just be converted to a string and it is showing `[Object object]` in the DOM on inspecting it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have  props: {
    result: Object,
  }, in both components.

Comment: @user13928344 Ideally it should work. Can you please put your sample `myResults` array in the post. So that it will make more clear.

Comment: Its an array of objects which is called using an Axios request. Im slightly unsure how to get the sample of the Array. Do you mean the  JSON file which holds the data?